# How to execute stored procedure in C# with different parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
 {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            foreach (var item in reportParams)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + item.ParameterName,  item.FieldValue ));
            }

            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
}
```

But this fails for some value to pass that if I change

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + item.ParameterName, "'" item.FieldValue"'" ));
```

Then failing condition passes and things working do no not passes.

What is the proper method to execute a stored procedure with any parameter value with or without "'"?

I am getting an error at `da.Fill(ds);` whenever the condition fails

Comment: When it fails what error do you get?

Comment: When it fails, what exception or error message you get? I think the right syntax should be `new SqlParameter("@" + item.ParameterName, item.FieldValue)` instead. With `"'"` I don't think it will compile.

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with your stored procedures, which could explain why they require the single quotes in certain cases. Please post a stored procedure that works without them and a stored procedure that doesn't work without them.

Answer (score 0):

public void ExecutePRC(string userId,ref string RetMsg)
        {
            try
            {

```
            string RetVal="";
            SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("ProcedureName",ConnectionObject);
            cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@USER_ID",SqlDbType.Int);

            SqlParameter outParameter = new SqlParameter("@RETVAL",SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
            outParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(outParameter);   

            outParameter = new SqlParameter("@RETMSG",SqlDbType.VarChar,255);
            outParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(outParameter);

            // assign Value to parameter userId
            cmd.Parameters["@USER_ID"].Value=userId;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            RetVal = cmd.Parameters["@RETVAL"].Value.ToString();
            RetMsg = cmd.Parameters["@RETMSG"].Value.ToString();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            //Use Ex.Message Exception
        }

    }
```

// InputParameter UserId (Int)
// OutputParameter REtVAL, RETMSG (varchar)

Comment: Seems totally irrelevant. Did you copy this code from somewhere else?

Comment: i have given simple example which i have implemented in my project so you Please refer it.

Comment: he needs to loop through a list of reportparameters, not add a single regular parameter, this code does not do anything close.

Comment: If You have same datatypes of parameter then it will easy to use for loops otherwise you have to add single single parameter

Comment: If you wan to execute proc with or without value parameter then you can set DBNULL.Value to Parameters